# Branch broke off in storm at trunk

Tags: trees, branches

In a recent storm two large branches broke off of my tree. They broke off right at the trunk, so I can't cut it back further to make it a clean cut. is there anything I should do to help protect the rest of the tree?

[image: Broken limbs of tree.]

---

**EDIT:** Here are some pictures that were requested:

The tree is in Southwest Ohio, near Cincinnati.

Tree as a whole. You can see essentially the whole back half came down. From the front of the tree though it still looks good.
[image: Side view of tree]

Side view of the broken section so you can get a better idea of how thick the tree is there: (Couldn't get a good side view because other branches were in the way.)
[image: Side a break]

Leaf:
[image: leaf of tree]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Major bummer!  There is not one thing you can do.  No painting or sealing.  All you can do now is wait to see if what got left for the vascular system will be able to deliver enough water and chemicals to support the canopy above that damage.

Where is it that you live?  Have you ever used the Cooperative Extension Service of your nearest University?  One thing you could actually do is to call them to get an arborist out to check this tree.  Very inexpensive.

I'd also call your Homeowner Association.  This looks as if it is in your front lawn which is also under the auspices of your HOA.  If this is one of the 'street or frontage' trees they are kind of in charge.  Appearance is everything to the HOA.  They dictate what kind of trees are in the front yards, the colors of the homes...I am guessing a Linden tree?

If the canopy above that damage is fairly large...looks like it might be...this tree could also be deemed dangerous.  Check these two organizations out and let us know what they say.  Another picture of the entire tree would be very helpful, as well as a closeup of those leaves!

Comment: The exact same thing happened to a friends tree a few days ago- I would recommend removing the tree altogether- it  could be structurally dangerous, it looks as if the breakage has gone directly into the core of the trunk- and with time it could lead to further damage in high winds- best remove to avoid any danger- sorry about the bad news.

Comment: I agree, this tree has a bad structure with many instances of included bark which are not  strong attachment point.  This tree could shed further branches sooner rather than later.  Consider replacing with different species from a quality supplier

Comment: This is exactly why I mentioned contacting the HOA about this tree.  They might raise a huge hissyfit with any other species THEY did not allow!  Sadly, OUR property is never OUR property.

Comment: @stormy the original poster does not mention an HOA.  Relevant if they have one but not otherwise

Comment: What development does not have an HOA?  Grins.  Great pictures he sent us...The damage doesn't look as bad as I was thinking.  He's got 3 major trunks, and if only this one dies, he's got the other two. But why did he lose the entire side of this tree?

Comment: See those utility boxes?  Sure sign this guy is on an HOA.  If he's not on a strict HOA I'll be surprised.

Comment: @EricJ  You do not want to replace this guy unless absolutely necessary.  You can see that your tree is way out of balance, not just looks but raw weight.  If I were you I'd call my nearest University Extension Service and find a reasonably priced arborist.  Have them come visit and help prune...diagnose this tree's chances.  Definitely call your HOA to ask about the 'rules' and their part of the responsibility.  This tree looks like it will be able to handle this damage with style.  You need a master pruner to get it back in balance. You need a tree ring around the base at least 3' in radius.

Comment: @stormy I will try to get an arborist to come out this week. I am glad to hear that the tree looks strong enough to make it. I will check with my HOA as well. As far as HOA's go mine is pretty easy going, but you are right that I should check with them before I do anything major.

Comment: Please let us know what he or she has to say!!  And your HOA as well.  Cross fingers!!

Comment: @stormy I had two different people come out and look at the tree, both felt that the tree was not safe and more branches would likely come down in a storm soon. Unfortunately we need to have the tree removed.

Comment: I can understand that that would be their recommendation.  This tree is important to the HOA 'look'.  Luckily, there is no disease dictating that you get another species altogether.  HOA's don't like that.  Too bad that someone wasn't willing to thin your tree by taking out a lot of the growth on the street side and making your tree more symmetrical.  So, will the HOA be amenable to taking your tree /out including roots then replacing with a tree of decent caliper?  Grins.  One could only hope.  How about your home owners insurance?  I'd not use that insurance unless the reason is dire...

Comment: @EricJ  Who did you call and went to your home for this diagnosis?

Comment: @stormy I found certified arborists using the treesaregood website. I don't recall both of their names. One of them was from West Chester Lawn Care. My HOA is pretty relaxed as far as this process goes. They do not require that I replace the tree, nor do they have any limits on what I replace it with. I am undecided at this point as to what I will do in that space.

Comment: At that size, I'd cut it down, and start over. When next you plant, start trimming yearly, up to a third of the canopy, to prevent so many branches, so close together. Having that invites that sort of catastrophe. Apparently this is not common knowledge, as I see two trees in my block that are going to rip themselves apart in 10 years.